# Cannot run tests with nosetests

Tags: python, django, nosetests

I am trying to use nosetests to run all test cases inside my project.

I cd to my project directory:

```
cd projects/myproject
```

Then I do:

```
nosetests
```

Which outputs:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

Inside projects/myproject I have a package called Encode and inside the package I have Test directory with tests:

```
Encode/
    __init__.py
    Video.py
    Ffmpeg.py
    Test/
        VideoTest.py
        FfmpegTest.py
```

Why is nosetests not detecting my unit tests? All of my unit test classes extend unittest.TestCase.

Comment: Did you specify the test runner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [nose docs](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html):

> Any function or class that matches the configured testMatch regular expression ((?:^|[\b_\.-])[Tt]est) by default – that is, has test or Test at a word boundary or following a - or _) and lives in a module that also matches that expression will be run as a test.

Your tests aren't being found because your filenames don't match the pattern.  Change them to Video_Test.py, or Test_Video.py, for example.  BTW: It's also odd that they have camelCase names like that, but that won't stop them from working.

Answer (score 1):

`nose` won't find your tests if they are buried in a subdirectory.  You should be able to tell it where to look though.  Try `nosetests --where=Encode/Test`.